# How to get keyCode in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the keycode as undefined .

I need to disable space button while entering password but am getting keyCode as undefined.

```
blockSpace(e) {
    e.persist();
    const key = e.keyCode;
    console.log("key", key);
     if (key === 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
    } 
  }
```

Above  console.log("key", key) is giving undefined

```
<GenericInputBox onChange ={this.blockSpace} />
```

I have checked similar stackoverflow post and included e.persist() in my code but still getting undefined .

Comment: can you add the HTML part where you call blockSpace?

Comment: @fahadtufail That's the same -_- as `onChange ={this.blockSpace}`

Comment: Try `onKeyDown={this. blockSpace}` event to capture keycode.

Comment: The change event fires after the input value has been modified, so even if it had a reference to the key (which it does not; there are many other ways to change the input value), it couldn't block specific characters. Try `oninput`, or in the onchange event remove spaces from the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onKeyDown resolved my issue , other logic is same - just used onKeyDown instead of onChange.onKeyPress too didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

`onKeyPress` the e.keyCode is always `0` and `e.charCode` have correct value. If you are using `onKeyDown` the correct code in `e.charCode`.

```
blockSpace(e) {
   e.persist();
   const key = e.keyCode;
   console.log("key", key);
    if (key === 32) {
     e.preventDefault();
   } 
 }

<GenericInputBox onKeyPress={this.blockSpace} />
```

If the code above still doesn't work you can try checking if the next code is space like:

```
blockSpace(e) {
   e.persist();
    const value = e.target.value;

    // check if value got a space anywhere
    if (value.includes(' ') {
     e.preventDefault(); // or whatever logic
   } 
 }
```

^^ if there's a space on the value then prevent default or whatever logic